# all site load in rendering partial view with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

When i load a partial view with this jquery :

```
$.get('@Url.Action( "List" , "Menu" )', function(data) {
    $('#treeviewdiv div').replaceWith(data);
});​
```

All sites load again inside my site. i mean another head tag, another body tag.

I use this and its not working too:

```
$.get('@Url.Action( "List" , "Menu" ) #container', function(data) {
    $('#treeviewdiv div').replaceWith(data);
});​
```

...and container is a div tag inside my partial view.

How can i fix it?

Comment: By chance is your Action returning a `PartialView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually indicative  of the action returning a full view and not a partial view. Good news is this can be solved simply with a few different options.

1 Make the action return a partial view:

```
public PartialViewResult Menu(){
  return PartialView();
}
```

2 If this is an action that could be called via ajax or standard methods, it may be helpful to toggle based on an ajax request:

```
public ActionResult Menu(){
  return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView() : View();
}
```

3 Another option is to let the view handle it for you (You can do this on the specific view or in the `ViewStart.cshtml` file):

```
@{
  Layout = !IsAjax ? "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" : null;
}
```